# How to Connect my mongoDb hosted in compute engine from App Engine also hosted in the same same region of project?

Tags: mongodb, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I created a Compute Engine Instance on which I am hosting my MongoDB server.
I also have a nodeJS server which currently hosted in APP Engine of the same project and in the same region.
Now I want to connect my MongoDB database with the AppEngine server.

How can I do this?

Please Guide me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So main question is *how* you're atttempting to connect from GAE to MongoDB, which is not included in your question...

This aside, you'll need the connection string, as per MongoDB documentation [1], and this doc shows how to get it [2].

Since you're running both GAE and the GCE instance running MongoDB in the same project you can use the internal IP address and you can remove the external IP address from the GCE instance to remove a potential security issue with people accessing MongoDB directly.

The connection string would be:

```
mongodb://[username:password@]GCE_INTERAL_IP[:port1][/[defaultauthdb][?options]]
```

Replace GCE_INTERAL_IP with the actual internal IP of the GCE instance running MongoDB. You can find this in the GCP console.

1. https://docs.mongodb.com/guides/server/drivers/#obtain-your-mongodb-connection-string
2. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/#mongodb-uri

Comment: Thanks u very much  for the guide.
I will definitely try it and let u know